# android, uninstall and install into the same activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, installation

I am trying to do an upgrade version process for apk files ...

How can i do to run uninstall and install Intent calls into the same activity?

If i do , uninstall intent,

```
    Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:" + paqueteId);
    Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE,packageURI);
    startActivityForResult(uninstallIntent, RESULT_OK);
```

is there anyway to wait for the uninstall finish and then continue running the activity code ... and then launch the install intent ???

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could register a broadcast reciever for `ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED` and wait for this, on this intent being called you could start the install

Comment: This will show the user the standard uninstall dialog. A App can't uninstall another App silently.

Comment: if you have system permissions, you can do it like how market app does. But otherwise for 3rd party applications that wont be possible. But if you are doing an upgrade with the same certificates, you do not need to uninstall. Android will automatically replace if you install a new app with same package AFAIK

Comment: um... paulononak show an example of silent upgrade, http://paulononaka.wordpress.com/2011/07/02/how-to-install-a-application-in-background-on-android/, but it needs google certs, app privileges .. i think i 've test only install, i think it is no ok, but, another problems, if app is running at time, the app is not restarted